# Autoload Feature File Format

Tags: azure-databricks

With the **Autoloader** feature, As per the documentation the configuration cloudFiles.format supports json, csv, text, parquet, binary and so on. Wanted to know if there is support for XML ?

Answer (score 1):

For streaming file data sources supported file formats are text, CSV, JSON, ORC, Parquet. My assumption is that only streaming file formats are supported.

Not sure if you got a chance to go through https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml for more complex xml-files with the spark-xml library . If you want to make use of this, auto loader won' t help.